# Apache Ambari patch information

Tags: apache, hadoop, ambari

How do you know which files need to be patched when Apache Ambari issues are resolved and a patch (ie. a diff) is attached to the corresponding JIRA issue? There is no description in the ticket as to which files need to be patched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch file contains all that information in the form of a diff. This includes which files were modified, what lines of code changed in that file, and how that line changed. Typically you would want to checkout the source code, apply the patch, and then build the project. If it's a change to a script or a configuration file you can just make those changes in an existing environment.